# Split one branch into two in Git

Tags: git, git-rewrite-history

I have a project with a completely linear history:

```
master    A – B – C – D – E – F – G – H
```

I'd like to split it into two: `develop` with most of the commits, and `master`, into which `develop` merges only at milestones:

```
master    A – – – D – – – – – H
           \     /           /
develop     B – C – E – F – G
```

Comment: You want to retroactively make the history of a git repository *more complex*? Why? What good would that do? This sounds like it's an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info).

Comment: @JoachimSauer Ha, I didn't know there was a name for it. But I don't think this is the case here, my X problem is actually just to learn Git beyond the very basics. As for making the history more complex, yes, true, but also more organized. Maybe I'll never use this but I think I'll benefit from the understanding I'll gain from doing it.

Comment: I suspect what you really want is for `D` and `H` to stay in the new develop branch, with new merge commits `D'` (with `A` and `D` as parents) and `H'` (with `D'` and `G` as parents). (Which I now notice is what more or less what @matt did in his answer.)

Comment: @chepner Yeah, I came to the same conclusion ...

Comment: @chepner You're right, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your diagram makes no sense; you cannot move D, for example, the way you have drawn it. Moreover, if no one else works on `master`, it doesn't make sense to make a separate merge commit on `master` as you have drawn it, because it can just be fast-forwarded to follow `develop`.

Nevertheless, we can do the *general* thing you describe, by forcing the existence of merge commits at various stages along the history. OK, so `master` is currently at H. Here we go:

1. Make a branch `develop` but do not check it out.
2. You are still on `master`. Reset `--hard` to A (using the SHA number). So now `master` is at A, and `develop` goes A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H.
3. You are *still* on `master`. Merge D `--no-ff` (using its SHA) to get a nice merge commit. Merge anywhere else along `develop` that you think is a meaningful staging point.
4. Checkout `develop` and keep working.

I will demonstrate. We have this:

```
* ddb5eeb (HEAD -> master) f
* d995c3c e
* a1f5432 d
* b6c9729 c
* b15090c b
* ee1de04 a
```

Now:

```
$ git branch develop
$ git reset --hard ee1d
$ git merge --no-ff a1f5
$ git merge --no-ff develop
$ git checkout develop
```

And we now have this:

```
*   2ad4bb2 (master) Merge branch 'develop'
|\  
| * ddb5eeb (HEAD -> develop) f
| * d995c3c e
* |   c6f43e4 Merge commit 'a1f5'
|\ \  
| |/  
| * a1f5432 d
| * b6c9729 c
| * b15090c b
|/  
* ee1de04 a
```

...which is just the sort of thing you said you wanted.

Comment: This is pretty much it, thanks. Like I said, I just want to learn Git, and I think this made me understand something I wasn't getting before.